# During a SQL migration/upgrade, is there an intuitive way to mirror the exact file paths of the old install without manually combing through?

Tags: sql-server-2016, migration, configuration

I am performing a migration upgrading from 2008 to 2016 and the requirements are that the file paths need to stay exactly the same as they were, with same drive letters, paths, and folder names due to the application being so static. I don't foresee it taking that much work to do this manually but I feel there must be a better way to mirror the config exactly. I know there will be some differrnt things no matter what inherently from upgrading the instance, but if anyone has any answers that would be very useful.

Thanks!

Comment: Why does the application care about SQL Server's drive letters, paths, and folder names? The application should be connecting to the instance, the underlying physical implementation should be irrelevant - this abstraction is part of the reason we use a relational database instead of a bunch of files on disk. :-)

Comment: I have no control over this really, it is for a client project and this is what the client is asking for. It is their application so it is hard to say, we do not manage the app. This is simply what they are requesting and I have to comply. You do bring up a good point, though. I am just hoping to make this easier on myself once I get to it.,

Comment: Are you performing an in-place upgrade or are you moving the databases to a new instance of SQL Server? (Also, these are questions you can pass along to your client. Just because you don't know or don't have control doesn't mean it's impossible to convince them that they're asking for something that is unnecessary.)

Comment: Entirely new VM and fresh instance, just migrating the data in after installation.

I agree with you, though. I am just in an unfortunate spot with this project, it has just been messy and a tight timeline is there, so we're a little beyond that. I already migrated and installed actually and they have since come out and asked for this to be done.

Comment: Though I will say this question as a whole may be entirely pointless since this situation is not really a SQL problem and you are correct in everything you're saying, so why would an answer exist. I guess I don't see why this functionality would be necessary.

Comment: So a lot of the file paths will be different, because many of them changed based on the version, instance name, x86 vs. x64, etc. You can add data and log folders that mimic the old structure, but this won't work for everything, and you'll have to manually set up all the permissions etc. too. Again, I would go back and solidify the actual requirements with the client, to save a bunch of your peers working on helping you with the extra effort required for something they likely don't even need.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, Aaron. I will close this question as I don't think there is a better answer unfortunately. Again, thanks much!